# Get MethodInfo of a function under a variable in C#

Tags: c#, lambda, expression, expression-trees, methodinfo

I have a specific object in C#, call it `MyCustomObject`. `MyCustomObject` is of type `MyNamespace.CustomObject`, and every object of that type contains a method `MyCustomMethod`. I am trying to get the `MethodInfo` (`System.Reflection.MethodInfo`) of `MyCustomObject.MyCustomMethod` so I can use it to create an expression tree later. However, if I just use `typeof(MyCustomObject).GetMethod("MyMethodInfo")`, it returns a general method for all objects of type `MyNamespace.CustomObject`. How can I get the `MethodInfo` of just `MyCustomObject.MyCustomMethod`?

Comment: There's no such thing. A method lives in a class, not in an instance of a class. You get the `MethodInfo` and `Invoke` it passing the instance you want

Comment: This question doesn't make much sense to me. I suspect OP just needs to use `myInstance.GetType()` instead of `typeof(MyCustomObject)`.

Comment: What I am trying to do is to construct an expression tree that calls ``MyCustomObject.MyCustomMethod``, and I went to use ``Expression.Call``, but I needed ``MethodInfo``. How can I construct an expression tree to call ``MyCustomObject.MyCustomMethod``?

Comment: @4yl1n You do exactly what you did.  That is the methodinfo you need to invoke that method on that type.

Comment: There is no such thing as a `MethodInfo` for a specific instance of an object. Think about how/what kind of code you would write in C# without using reflection, and post that to explain what you are trying to do.

Comment: @JohnWu the OP hasn't described any class hierarchy inheriting from `MyNamespace.CustomObject`, so `myInstance.GetType()` would return an equivalent `Type` to `typeof(MyCustomObject)`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When creating your expression tree (per [this comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63623144/get-methodinfo-of-a-function-under-a-variable-in-c-sharp#comment112506693_63623144)), you presumably want to use the [`Call`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.expressions.expression.call) factory method.

In your case, you're trying to create an expression tree representing an **instance method call**, not a **static method call**; the difference between them is that an instance method call uses an instance, while a static method call does not.

To create such an expression tree, you'll need some kind of expression tree that represents the instance; it might be a property or field, or the result of another method call. But if you want to apply it to an existing instance, you could pass your instance into the `Constant` factory method.

You could pass this node into one of the `Call` overloads which represent an instance method call, such as [this one](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.expressions.expression.call?view=netcore-3.1#System_Linq_Expressions_Expression_Call_System_Linq_Expressions_Expression_System_Reflection_MethodInfo_), for an instance method call with no arguments.

Something like this:

```cs
// using System.Linq.Expressions.Expression

CustomObject MyCustomObject = /* initialized somehow */
var methodInfo = typeof(CustomObject).GetMethod("MyCustomMethod");
var expr = Lambda(
    Call(
        Constant(MyCustomObject),
        methodInfo
    ),
    new ParameterExpression[] { }  // if the LambdaExpression has parameters, add them here
);
```

---

#### Addendum

When using the compiler to generate a similar expression tree:

```
CustomObject MyCustomObject = /* initialized somehow */
Expression<Action> expr = () => MyCustomObject.MyCustomMethod();
```

`MyCustomObject` isn't represented with a `ConstantExpression`, but rather with a `MemberAccessExpression`. The C# compiler rewrites closed-over variables (in this case, `MyCustomObject` within the lambda expression) as a property access on a compiler-generated object. Instead of the call to `Constant`, the corresponding factory methods to represent `MyCustomObject` would look something like this:

```
// using System.Linq.Expressions.Expression

PropertyOrField(
    Constant(<<closure_object>>),
    "MyCustomObject"
)
```

We can't write something like this in code, because our code doesn't have access to the `<<closure_object>>` instance.